# Speed up query if many SP's based on the same Tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

I have a eight tsql stored procedures that are called everytime i load a form in my vb.net program. The querys look which windowsuser sends the query and gives the result depending on it. 
The structure of the procedures is always the same except for the last statement:

```
Create Procedure dbo.Name @one decimal(18,2) Output as 
...
Create Table #Temp1
Insert Into
...
Create Table #Temp2
Insert Into
...
Select ...
```

The last Select Statement changes in all eight SP's and uses Temp1 and Temp2 information and sends the query depending on the user who is logged in. Everything works fine but it is very slowly since every eight queries are triggered by the load_event. What is the best way to speed that up?

Comment: Post an entire procedure

Comment: hi! my sp is 180 rows long that is why i just use the structure here.

Comment: We need more to go on. 8 queries actually isn't that bad... it's almost certainly your use of temp tables that's causing the real problem here, but we can't help you unless we can see some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always using all eight procs together, then combine them into one and only create the temp tables once.

You can also index temp tables if you need to improve their speed.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a performance issue, for SQL Server 2000 and above, you can try using table variables (prefixed with `@`) instead of temporary tables.